# Ivy - adding a maven repository fails

Tags: maven, android-activity, ivy

I want to add activity-engine dependency through ivy like this:

*ivy.xml:*

```
<dependency org="org.activiti" name="activiti-engine" rev="5.14" />
```

*ivysettings:*

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="default" />
<resolvers>
    <chain name="default">
        <ibiblio name="internal" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
            root="http://10.8.202.21:8081/archiva/repository/internal" />
        <!-- Public Maven repository -->
        <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />   
        <ibiblio name="workflow" m2compatible="true"  root="https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"/>  
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

When I resolved the dependency in Eclipse, I got the error:

> unresolved dependency: org.activiti#activiti-engine;5.14: not found

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be working. If you want to force the resolver you could add a modules directive:

```
<modules>
  <module organisation="org.activiti" resolver="public"/>
</modules>
```

I find the use of modules very powerful as it enables me explicitly control which repository is used to to retrieve dependencies. The following is an example:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="3rdparty" />
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="3rdparty">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" />
      <ibiblio name="repo1" m2compatible="true" root="http://.."/>
      <ibiblio name="repo2" m2compatible="true" root="http://.."/>
      ..     
    </chain>
    <ibiblio name="internal" m2compatible="true" root="http://my.repo.com/.."/>
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation="my.org" resolver="internal"/>
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```